# Offline speech recognition in html/javascript page

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I wanted a speech recognition library that works in html page with the help of javascript, and that can be used OFFLINE (in localhost without Internet).

(Also I don't want to add words to recognize manually, I want to set (English) or (Arabic) for example and recognize the entire talk to text in output div).

Comment: Help about a particular script is off-topic here, so I removed that part from your question, please feel free to ask about that part at superuser.com though.

Comment: Same as https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/58060/speech-recognition-javascript-api-that-recognizes-standard-hardcoded-words-via-p